# Multiple model in one model Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want to create multiple model in one form.

This is my controller:

```
public function actionWorkRoom() {
    $model = [new Moshtari()];
    $model[0] = new Moshtari();
    $model[1] = new Moshtari();
    if (Model::loadMultiple($model, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($model)) {
        foreach ($model as $m) {
            $m->save(false);
        }            
   }
    return $this->render('_form_work_room', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

Model:

```
    class Moshtari extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
        public function rules() {
                return [
                    [['CodeKargah'], 'number'],
                ]
        }
        public function attributeLabels() {
             return [
                'CodeKargah' => Yii::t('app', 'Code Kargah'),
             ];
    }

    }
```

And this is my form in view:

```
foreach ($model as $index => $m) {
     echo $form->field($m, "[$index]CodeKargah");
}
```

but this is throwing this error:

> Call to a member function getActiveValidators() on a non-object

Comment: What is your full error and what is the line of code mentioned?

Comment: full error http://www.dsabz.com/view/files/q.PNG

Comment: Is there a rule for `CodeKargah`?

Comment: Yes there is rule.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved, this is new code:

Controller:

```
public function actionWorkRoom($member = 1) {
    $model[] = new Moshtari(['scenario' => 'work_room_kargah']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $member; $i++) {
        $model[] = new Moshtari(['scenario' => 'work_room']);
    }
    if (Model::loadMultiple($model, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($model)) {
        foreach ($model as $m) {
            $m->time = Yii::$app->jdate->date('Y/m/d') . ' ' . date('H:i:s');
            $m->CodeKargah = $model[0]->CodeKargah;
            $m->save(false);
        }
        return $this->redirect('index');
    }

    return $this->render('_form_work_room', ['models' => $model]);
}
```

View

```
foreach ($models as $index => $model) {
    //print_r($model->getErrors());
    if ($index >= 1) {
                    <?=
                    $form->field($model, "[$index]name", [
                        'template' => '<div class="row nomargin"><div class="col-md-4 form_label">{label}</div><div class="col-md-7">{input}{error}</div></div>']
                    )->textInput(['maxlength' => true])
                    ?>
    }
}
```